# .append or .after defined as a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So I'm trying to figure out the best way to get this to work. I have a long list of code that's pulling off of a JSON database, and I'm trying to streamline it. I've created the following function:

```
var insertData = function(formattedData, originalData, referencePoint, insertPoint, insertStyle) {
  var formattedData = originalData.replace("%data%", referencePoint);
  $(insertPoint).insertStyle(formattedData);
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Is it possible to define a dot function similar to how I have it here - referenced as one of the function's variables? This current code says that `insertStyle` is not a function - how do I get the code to recognize that `insertStyle` should be taking a variable name? As in, if my fifth variable called by `insertData` is append, it should be read as `.append`.

As a reference, here's how I'm calling the function:

```
insertData("formattedHeaderName", "HTMLheaderName", bio.name, "#header", "prepend");
```

Thanks for any assistance or thoughts in advance!

Comment: `var formattedData = formattedData;`  All the lines like this are unnecessary; passing in parameters already defines those variables scoped to the function.

Comment: Ah woops, thanks for the heads up, editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a computed property:

```
$(insertPoint)[insertStyle](formattedData);
```

Basically, every property access can be represented as a computed property:

```
foo["bar"];  // same as foo.bar
```

In your original code, you're using a non-computed property so the interpreter looks for a method literally called "insertStyle", which doesn't exist.

Comment: Following that, I get the error  $(...)[insertStyle] is not a function... is there something I might be missing? Have tried the following values: prepend "prepend" ".prepend" .prepend and they all throw the same error.

Comment: You should use the actual method name as a string `"prepend"`. Please double check that your code in your post matches what you're trying to do in your project-- from what I can see with the two snippets, what I've said here should work.

Comment: Found a typo when I was rewriting, again, appears to be prepending appropriately now, thanks!

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Can you suggest any documentation about this way to use computed property ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette You might like either https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an argument to a function, like you do in:

```
insertData("formattedHeaderName", "HTMLheaderName", bio.name, "#header", "prepend");
```

Those arguments are strings. Not jQuery methods.

So, a solution would be to define all the methods you need to use...
And just compare the string passed to decide.

```
var insertData = function(formattedData, originalData, referencePoint, insertPoint, insertStyle) {

  var formattedData = originalData.replace("%data%", referencePoint);

  if(insertStyle=="prepend"){
    $(insertPoint).prepend(formattedData);
  }
  if(insertStyle=="append"){
    $(insertPoint).append(formattedData);
  }
  if(insertStyle=="after"){
    $(insertPoint).after(formattedData);
  }
  // And so on...
}
```

Maybe there is some other ways to achive this...
But this one is quick and easy to implement.